# Why can't I use my @ubuntu.com mail address to register an Ubuntu One account?

Tags: ubuntu-one

When I try to do so, it tells me:

This email address cannot be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got that same error when attempting to use mine. I then found an email in my inbox that said.

"We've received a request to create a new account with tgm4883@ubuntu.com, however an account is already registered with this email address."

So then I used the "Forgot your password?" link and I received an email at my ubuntu.com address to change my password. What is odd is that the link to reset my password was for my primary email address that is listed in launchpad (which is where ubuntu.com forwards to).

So my guess is that when Ubuntu One sees an email address for a ubuntu.com account, it queries launchpad to find the actual email address that it should use. It then links both email addresses to the same account.

Comment: oh yeah you are right. I even got a mail which told me : We've received a request to create a new account with gotwig@ubuntu.com, however an account is already registered with this email address.

Answer (score 1):

Because you already have an Ubuntu One account.

In order to have an ubuntu.com e-mail address, you must already have an account on Launchpad. An account on Launchpad is indifferent from an Ubuntu One account. You simply need to log in, rather than attempt to register a new address.

Whether you log into Launchpad, Ubuntu Wiki, Ubuntu One, or the Software Center, it's all the same account. See https://login.ubuntu.com/+ubuntuone-account for more information.